# iPhone SDK of runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage is private API?

Tags: iphone, app-store, iphone-privateapi

My iPhone application which use the WebView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage, 
but I can not find in the iPhone API documentation of this method, 
only the Mac OS API documentation to find it, 
I am worried that if use this method will not be on the frame in the Appstore, 
but if can not use this method I do not know how to do, 
any ideas?

Comment: hi! same here..
any solution? thanks